# Run command from terminal window in AWS Instance at specified time or on start up

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloud9

I have a AWS Cloud9 Instance that starts running at 11:52 PM MST and stops running at 11:59 PM MST. I have a dockerfile within the Instance that when ran with the correct mount will run a set of c++ .cpp files that collect live web data. The ultimate goal of this instance is to be fully automatic so that every night it collects the live web data for that date, hence why the Instance is open at the very end of the day each night. Is it possible to have my AWS Instance run a given command in a terminal window at a certain time, say 11:55 PM or even upon startup. So at the time, or at startup, the command "docker run -it...." is ran within the instance.

Is automating this process possible? I have looked into CloudWatch events and think that might be the best way to go about automating this process but I am not quite sure how I would create a rule to fulfill the job. If it is not possible to automate a certain command within a terminal window, could I automate the dockerfile to run at a certain time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ofcourse you can automate running of commands not just docker but for the fact any commands using **cron daemon**. all you need to do is place your command in shell script file say doc.sh in your desired directory.

1. ssh into your instance
2. open terminal and type `crontab -e`
3. enter the following details in this manner `a b c d e /directory/command`

where a -Minute, b-hour c-day d-month e-day of the week
the `/directory/command` specifies the location and script you want to run.

for more reference [cron examples](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/set-up-cron-job-linux),https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

Comment: Thank you for the links, I have read through them but still have a few questions. Right now I have the contrab -e set to 55 23 * * * /home/ec2-user/environment/myubuntu/docker.sh. I am hoping this means that at 11:55 it will run docker.sh, but I am curious if contrab knows my time is MST or if I need to alter the time for a different time zone. Additionally, I have never used .sh so I am not quite sure if I did it right. My .sh has two lines, #!/bin/bash and docker run -it --mount type=bind,source="/home/ec2-user/environment/Project", source="... Does any of this seem right/how do I test it?

Comment: Cron job uses the server's define timezone (UTC by default) which you can check by typing the `date` command in terminal, it will output which timezone your server is using hence your CRON,if you want to run cron with different timezone just add ` CRON_TZ=MST` before your corn entry( if your timezone is different).
for the second doubt if  want to check the execution of your .sh file you can do it on terminal using `chmod +x /path to your sh file`(execution permission) and then ./docker.sh ( . refers to same working directory) or you can also run it as root user -`sudo bash docker.sh`

Comment: Final question, if I then wanted to run a `docker container prune` could I place that within my docker.sh? I would not want the prune to take place until after the docker has fully run the code so I am guessing there might be some timing overlap that causes issues. If there are timing issues I would assume I could make a different .sh file for the docker container prune and a different cron job to run it but how would I ensure the correct user input? Running `docker container prune` then requires y or n input so I am not sure how to ensure that the prune process is completed properly

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dockerfile that you want to run for a few minutes a day, you should look into Fargate.  You can schedule an event with Cloudwatch, run the container and then shut it down when it's done.

It will probably cost around $0.01/day to run this.